# Creating a 2D array of objects vs ints for chess game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, multidimensional-array

I'm currently in the process of making a multiplayer chess game in Javascript + HTML5 canvas as a mini side project. I would like to know what the best practice would be for representing the board.

Option 1: 2D Array of Objects
 - I have a Piece module with some functions common to all board pieces. I then have objects for all the pieces that inherit from Piece.
 - I can then make a 2D Array of Pieces with 32 total objects and set their position on the board.

Option 2: 2D Array of Ints
 - I can simple make a 2D grid where a certain integer represents a given piece.

Which option would be 'best', or is there a better one? I am trying to take a OO approach overall.

Appreciate any input. Thanks guys.

Comment: Option 1 would give you the most flexibility - each object could still contain an integer that identifies the piece, but it could also contain info like the type of piece, and if it's white or black:
`pieces = [ { id: 1, side: 'white', type: 'pawn' }, ... ]

Going with option two seems like you'd just be limiting yourself, with little or no benefit. If the goal is to go OO overall, go with objects!

Comment: Personally I would go with 2D array of Objects so I can easily get information like what piece is on that position, what is the color of the box, what player does the piece belong to etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well go for objects, to learn OOP, to have a code that is overall 'nicer' … If you were programming a game with a significantly larger 'board', i.e. with size in the thousands or more tiles, you might consider the integer approach for performance reasons.

An 8 x 8 chessboard, however, is nothing for a modern JS interpreter, so might as well go crazy.

Comment: Do I make 32 seperate objects (8 pawn objects, 2 knight objects, etc for each player) or do I make 6 objects and use them when needed?

The second option make it tricky in terms of storing positions, but the first option requires 32 variables...

Comment: Once again, 32 variables is not a big deal. Obviously don't store them as individual variables in the global scope, have them in an array representing the board … Empty squares are just `null`s, some will be filled with an object that you can move around / remove and replace with a different one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array of Objects would probably be a better choice as you can store more data than an array of ints. For example, instead of using the numbers 5 and 6 to represent black and white pawns, you could have an object with a property of type and a property of color.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's more convenient to use an array of objects for representing the board, that way you can easily attach each Piece object and its graphical representation (CSS class), while using numbers to represent a piece seems to me as a more messier approach and definitely not OO.